# Mosquitto does not connect to AWS

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, aws

I'm new to AWS services, I'm still studying the docs. I received a quite long (working) Python code that exchange data with the Cloud.

Now I want to pub/sub messages with `mosquitto`.
Basically I'm trying the following:

```
mosquitto_sub -h <id>.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 443 -t "$aws/things/<sn>/shadow/update/delta" --cafile ./root-CA.crt --cert ./<sn>.cert.pem --key ./<sn>.private.key -d -i <sn>
```

Where:

- `<id>` is the prefix of the host
- `<sn>` is the serial-number of the board

That command leads to:

> Client  sending CONNECT

and nothing else.
I found a policy document inside a Python script (to be used when creating the device):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:client/<sn>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:topic/$aws/things/<sn>/shadow/update",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:topic/IoTData"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:topicfilter/$aws/things/<sn>/shadow/update/accepted",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:topicfilter/$aws/things/<sn>/shadow/update/rejected",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:<id>:topicfilter/$aws/things/<sn>/shadow/update/delta"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is "attached" to the certificates, and even reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/attach-policy.html) I'm not sure if the CLI command is referred to my target's console (an RPi).

### UPDATE

From the AWS console I create a new certificate and downloaded the three files to the target: `<xxx>-certificate.pem.crt`, `<xxx>-private.pem.key`, `<xxx>-public.pem.key`. Then I attached the policy to this certificated (from the AWS console itself).

Still the connection is not completed and no answer is received.

Comment: Swap the `"` for `'` round the topic, with double quotes the shell will try to expand`$aws` as an environment variable (which probably doesn't exist)

Comment: @hardillb, done. Unfortunately nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to attach the policy to the certificate and set the port to 8883 because the protocol is MQTT and not MQTT over Websockets.